# Filter Array to get specific result between values

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 24 results from the database, which includes the year and month.
the goal is:
I know the month and year that was selected, so I get the results for the current year and the previous year, which results in the array of 24.

now I want to get the results for the current month and the previous 11 months.

I still haven't realized how I can do this, I have some tests performed by me here, which is what I currently have but is not correct:

```js
const data = [
  { Data: '01/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '01', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '02/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '02', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '03/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '03', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '04/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '04', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '05/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '05', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '06/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '06', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '07/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '07', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '08/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '08', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '09/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '09', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '10/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '10', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '11/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '11', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '12/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '12', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '01/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '01', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '02/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '02', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '03/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '03', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '04/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '04', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '05/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '05', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '06/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '06', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '07/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '07', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '08/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '08', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '09/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '09', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '10/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '10', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '11/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '11', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '12/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '12', year: '2020' }
]
  const Year = '2020'
  const Month = '11'
  const finalfilter = data.filter(location => location.year === Year)
  console.log(finalfilter)
```

Expected result shoud be after aplly the filter to get the previous 11 months of the selected month:

```
const result = [
  { Data: '12/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '12', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '01/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '01', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '02/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '02', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '03/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '03', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '04/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '04', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '05/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '05', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '06/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '06', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '07/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '07', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '08/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '08', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '09/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '09', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '10/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '10', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '11/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '11', year: '2020' },
]
```

Comment: You should add your expected output to your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And what is the actual problem with that approach?

Comment: _“for the current month and the previous 11 months”_ - so that would be all the records where the year is the current year and the month is <= `Month`, plus all those where the year is the previous year and the month is > `Month` then, innit …?

Comment: hi, just edited the concept, i hope now is mor explicit

Comment: @CBroe ya is almost like that, see the exeple os expected result pls

Comment: Not “almost”, but _exactly_. So all you have to do is _implement_ these conditions now …

Comment: Code snippets only make sense when there's something "meaningful" to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `filter` [find the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the object you need then [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) out the objects before it to create a new array.

```js
const data=[{Data:"01/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"01",year:"2019"},{Data:"02/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"02",year:"2019"},{Data:"03/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"03",year:"2019"},{Data:"04/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"04",year:"2019"},{Data:"05/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"05",year:"2019"},{Data:"06/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"06",year:"2019"},{Data:"07/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"07",year:"2019"},{Data:"08/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"08",year:"2019"},{Data:"09/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"09",year:"2019"},{Data:"10/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"10",year:"2019"},{Data:"11/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"11",year:"2019"},{Data:"12/01/2019 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"12",year:"2019"},{Data:"01/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"01",year:"2020"},{Data:"02/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"02",year:"2020"},{Data:"03/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"03",year:"2020"},{Data:"04/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"04",year:"2020"},{Data:"05/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"05",year:"2020"},{Data:"06/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"06",year:"2020"},{Data:"07/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"07",year:"2020"},{Data:"08/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"08",year:"2020"},{Data:"09/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"09",year:"2020"},{Data:"10/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"10",year:"2020"},{Data:"11/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"11",year:"2020"},{Data:"12/01/2020 00:00:00",location:"2",month:"12",year:"2020"}];

const year = '2020';
const month = '11';

const index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.year === year && obj.month === month);

const newArr = data.slice(index - 11, index + 1);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Only works when there's an object for every month of the year.

Comment: And if it's sorted.

Comment: I can only base my answer on the information provided in the question. I just assume that the data is correct otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: You should then at least add these assumptions/restrictions into your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function to get the different in months between the dates, then filter to ensure this is greater than or equal to 0 and below 12:

```js
const data = [
  { Data: '01/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '01', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '02/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '02', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '03/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '03', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '04/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '04', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '05/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '05', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '06/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '06', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '07/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '07', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '08/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '08', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '09/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '09', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '10/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '10', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '11/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '11', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '12/01/2019 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '12', year: '2019' },
  { Data: '01/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '01', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '02/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '02', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '03/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '03', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '04/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '04', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '05/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '05', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '06/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '06', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '07/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '07', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '08/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '08', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '09/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '09', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '10/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '10', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '11/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '11', year: '2020' },
  { Data: '12/01/2020 00:00:00', location: '2', month: '12', year: '2020' }
]
const Year = 2020;
const Month = 11;

function getMonthDiff(year1, month1, year2, month2) {
  return (year1 - year2) * 12 + month1 - month2;
}

const finalfilter = data.filter(location => { 
    return (getMonthDiff(Year, Month, location.year, location.month) >= 0) && 
    (getMonthDiff(Year, Month, location.year, location.month) < 12);
    
});
console.log(finalfilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `let` instead of `const` and this filter:

```
let Year = '2020';
let Month = '11';
let finalfilter = data.filter(
     location => location.year == Year && location.month <= Month || location.year == Year-1 && location.month > Month
);
```

Comment: _"You could use `let` instead of `const`"_ - Why?

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests that, hence the "recommendation" to use `let` to solve this problem makes no sense.

Comment: thats not a problem , i understand his concept,

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL That might be the case, but unnecessary (and possible harmful) changes don't have a place in a good/valuable answer.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for your careful consideration.